# "Admin" user automatically has sudo privileges

Tags: user-management, privileges, adduser

I added a user named "admin" to my Ubuntu 14.04LTS server, using `adduser`.

I'm used to having to add a user to the `/etc/sudoers` file when adding a new user that needs sudo privileges, but this time I didn't.  It doesn't appear the 'admin' user existed before I created it, based on the output in the shell.  Why did this work this way?

Comment: Instead of manually editing the sudoers file, add them to the `admin` group.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

By default `adduser` adds every new user to a group with the same name as the user's (the group is created if it doesn't already exists). So if you create a user called `admin` it will be added to the group `admin`.

`/etc/sudoers` contains the line

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

which means that all members of the group `admin` are allowed to use `sudo` - and that's true for your `admin` user, too.

Comment: Side note: This is also true for the Polkit admin privileges.

Comment: This falls inside the definition of "bug" or "security problem" in my view. Why should there be a magic sequence of letter that gives you superpowers if you use it as your username?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni agree with you, although someone trying to exploit this would have to call `adduser`, which would mean he already has admin privileges... Still, worth adding a bug report I would think

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Bug, not at all. The system adds users to their own group with the same name. `Joe` goes into a group named `Joe`. `admin` happens to go into a group named `admin`. But, `admin` is a system group. It's the group by default allowed to use sudo. Also, you can specify groups, so the `admin` user doesn't go into the `admin` group. Finally, it's a security problem to have a user named `admin`. I've had SSH brute-force attacks against me relying on my using the username `admin`.

Comment: @Whaaaaaat, for some reason, seeing that username at the end of your posts makes me question everything you say  :)

Comment: @trpt4him And, that's why I chose that.

Comment: I think that given the policy of one user - one group, the expected behavior (at least, for me) is to bail out with an error if the group name exists (as it does if the user name exists). I vote for the bug, or at least unexpected behavior.

Comment: The group "admin" was probably added to allow "admin" users on a LAN consisting of a mix of Novell, Linux and Unix serwers, at that time it was thought a good thing for Admin users on Lan's!